# Finding last used row in a table then adding data to the remaining rows below

Tags: vba, excel

I've been googling this one for a while now with no success - I have a table with around 850 rows and in columns 8 to 13 I need to find the last *used* row, and then add data to the remaining empty rows below (if any). I've found plenty of examples working with ranges but they all just find the last row in the table and as such don't work for me. I'm a beginner with VBA and I've tried working with the ListColumns object but to no avail, and as such have no current code to post. Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Have a look here for a good resource on tables: [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables). Try to solve your issue and if you come up with a more specific question post the code you already have and what's going wrong. Also read [ask] to see how a good question should look like.

Comment: Thanks Peh. I do realise that, and my apologies for the lack of clarity on the question. But I have read through that resource, along with Ron de Bruin's pages on Tables and other sites, and I haven't been able to find any answer to finding the last used row in a table column. Maybe I'm just missing it. Thanks for the How to Ask link btw, I'll follow its guidance in future!

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i, iColumn, Ending_Column As Long ' Declare you long data types

    Ending_Column = 13 ' Assing the right-most column

    i = Range("H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1 ' Find the next row column H (this lets you enter the data on the same line)

    For iColumn = 8 To Ending_Column ' Asign left-most column and loop to the right-most one
        Cells(i, iColumn).Value = "Your input" ' The "Your input" needs to be modified
    Next ' next column

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - unfortunately I'm getting a 1004 error on the input line, and after doing some testing I don't believe the code to find the next row is working properly either. As I'm working with a table object the code finds the last row in the table, not the last row of data in the column. For example, the table ends at row 857, but in column 8 the last row containing data is row 850. If I use some test code similar to yours:

Comment: `Sub TEST()
Dim Lrow As Long
With Sheets("Reorder guide")
    Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With
MsgBox Lrow
End Sub` Then I get a result of 858, rather than 850.

Comment: @Jeremy Please never assume the worksheet always use full qualified ranges like in [VBA Best Practices - Never Assume the Worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet). Also you need to declare all 3 variables as long `Dim i As Long, iColumn As Long, Ending_Column As Long` because in `Dim i, iColumn, Ending_Column As Long` only the last variable is `long` the first 2 are `variant`.

Comment: @Peh When you're talking about the fully qualified range are you referring to my `Range("H"`... (as opposed to `Cells([column],8]`)

Comment: @Jeremy yes both `Range` and `Cells` should be fully qualified like this `shtMySheet.Cells(i, j).Value` assuming `Set shtMySheet = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`. Another thing is that you first set `i = Range(...)` but later you use `i` as numeric value in `Cells(i, …)` that's not working.

Comment: @Peh You're right on the `i` - it's a long data type (which i Intended to use it as) but due to a syntax error it was actually assigned as a range (now corrected). On the fully qualified piece, there wasn't any reference made to sheet name in the OP, that's why I didn't fully qualify (it may not be "Sheet1"

Comment: @Jeremy Yes I understand and I had to make this decision several times too. But I suggest it's still better teaching to fully qualify it and leave a comment that the OP has to change the sheet name to his need then.